# Find all the values of x for the given function where the tangent line is horizontal

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

f(x)=${\sqrt{x^2+10x+34}}$

The answer choices are

A. -5,5

B. 0,-5

C. -5

D. 0,5

Using the chain rule I have found the derivative of this problem as

$(2x+10)$${1 \over2(x^2+10x+34)^1/2}$

Given that derivative when I plug in 0 to try and find the where the first derivative is equal to zero I end up with y=3

-5 is the only value where when I plug it in it seems to give me anything close to 3. Can anyone tell me if I am on the right track or what else I should try to do to solve this problem?

Comment: It happens to be the case that $f(-5)=3$, but the $3$ is totally irrelevat to the problem at hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivative seems to be correct, but then you get off track. Note that the fraction $\frac{2x+10}{2(x^2+10x+34)^{1/2}}$ is zero iff the numerator is zero. Thus you want to solve $2x+10=0$, which leads to $x=-5$. Also, be sure to check that the value found is in the domain of $f$ in the first place (it is).

Comment: Ohhhhhh okay thank you very much.